# How several OpenMP compilers create threads?

Tags: openmp

How several OpenMP compilers create threads? I think that this may depend on concrete compiler (GCC, ICPC and Visual C++). But maybe they use some libraries like pthread..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the implementations use pthreads, since the pthreads library is on Linux and Windows.  This simplifies the implementation, since they don't have to change the implementation depending on the operating system.  The one implementation (of course) that differs is Microsoft.  Since they only support Windows, they use the Window's threading APIs.  At least on Linux, you can check for yourself what threading model is being used, by using nm on the OpenMP run time library and seeing what the external dependencies are.